# How to read data from excel in cucumber

Tags: excel, selenium, cucumber, data-driven-tests

I have to read excel where excel have employee name,process,start date,end date and employee id columns.In excel,For each employees process is different,(process i have to select from dropdown in UI),start date ,end date.I have to fetch all this details from excel and i have to capture employee id after creation of employee and put back to the excel.How do i do it using cucumber?

Comment: The way to do tabular data testing in Cucumber is with a Scenario Outline. You will have to use a custom mechanism to update the spreadsheet. I suggest that if you want to do data-driven testing, you do it outside of Cucumber.

Comment: if not using data driven how do i automate this scenario in cucumber?Because for each process you select from dropdown,the next step will be different.scenarios are not constant.Do you want me to use if else condition?if(process equals abc){do xyz) if(process equals def)(do lmn)?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your data as it is and Cucumber are compatible. It is hard to say without seeing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have an application where i have to search a member and for the member, i have to assign process(from drop down).But depending on the process I select ,I have to write next step.Ex:for ABC employee if i select XYZ as process,then next step will be clickButton,and simillarly for LMN employee if i select PQR as process,next step will be assignUser.So till selecting process the steps are common.Ho w do you write this in cucumber.I mean in feature and step defination files

Comment: I'd bundle similar conditions together in the same scenario outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use Cucumber tables e don´t need use excel files.

For read excel files, you will need to create an extensive excel reading class.

Why using Excel is an anti-pattern? click [here](https://ultimateqa.com/automation-patterns-antipatterns/)

You can use scenario outline for example:

```
Feature: Calculator
  As a user
  I want to use a calculator to add numbers
  So that I don't need to add myself

  Scenario Outline: Add two numbers <num1> & <num2>
    Given I have a calculator
    When I add <num1> and <num2>
    Then the result should be <total>

  Examples: 
    | num1 | num2 | total |
    | -2 | 3 | 1 |
    | 10 | 15 | 25 |
    | 99 | -99 | 0 |
    | -1 | -10 | -11 |
```